# Is there an anti-commutator analog of Zassenhaus formula?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, generating-functions

Is anyone familiar with an anti-commutator analog [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula/)? I have been able to find the [anti-commutator analog of the BCH formula](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4877v1)
$$e^ABe^A= B + \{B,A\}+\frac{1}{2!}\{\{B,A\},A\}+ \frac{1}{3!}\{\{\{B,A\},A\},A\} \cdots,$$
thus I believe that there should also exist one for Zassenhaus.